# Channel Images - can't find other sizes

Tags: ee2, add-on, channel-images

So I just purchased my first copy of Channel Images and installed it without issue. I then proceeded to add a field and then add images to an an entry. All went smoothly. However I can't seem to find out how to create different sized images. In the entry page there's a tab for SIZES but nothing happens when I click on it.

I used the following template code from the docs

```
{exp:channel_images:images}
  <a href="{image:url}"><img src="{image:url:medium}" /></a>
{/exp:channel_images:images}
```

Which spits out the following image url `<img src="{image:url:medium}">` Likely since I haven't created a medium image, but I don't see where to do this and there's no information in the [documentation](http://www.devdemon.com/docs/channel_images/index.html).

[image: entry screenshot]

So my question is - how do I create different sized images using channel images and is there anything else that I am missing that is not in the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a new size is pretty easy actually. It's done in the fieldtype settings.

This image should say it all.

[image: Fieldtype Settings]

Comment: Hmmm when I created the field the options weren't there, but that was probably due to the themes not getting picked up since I moved them using the new option in 2.5.3. Moved theme to default location and I now see that i can create different sizes.

Comment: Someone should probably send a bug report to the DevDemon folks if their themes don't work when moved!

Answer (score 2):

You set up image sizes on the custom field edit form for your specific field.